# Laravel - Session in controller get the last value that was set

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm trying to store values inside session in laravel..
I want to store a value to get the last value that was set.

i Have this route

web.php

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{lol}', 'MyController@test');
});
```

Mycontroller

```
public function test($lol){

    if($lol == "lol" ){
        session(['lol' => $lol]);
    }

    dd(session()->get('lol'));

}
```

http://localhost/laravel/v1/lol = > return value! OK!

http://localhost/laravel/v1/123 => return null!, why???

I want to return lol, because i need the last value stored in session.

I supose that $_SESSION in php works well for that purpose.

but in Laravel i cant use this.

Comment: You want to store a value to get the last value that was set. Can you explain this part?

Comment: http://localhost/laravel/v1/lol = > save here

http://localhost/laravel/v1/123 => retrive here in stored session

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem you are facing. It's actually working as you expected in my server.

Answer (score 1):

Session data is written in `terminable middleware` which is only applied `after the request has been sent`. Therefore if you're trying to use session variables throughout your code `before` you have returned the request, this will not work.

The way that you're using sessions here will not work.

Answer (score 1):

**I used this piece of code:**
[image]

Basically the same code that you did, one thing that I notice that you're able to set values in the session of laravel **after** you loggin in your application, you **must** be authenticated.
When I'm tring this piece of code I got the same error, the session in the second request is null